# ioService.post(boost::bind(&myFunction, this, attr1, attri2) does not post the work

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

I have a program which takes several input from the user and based on the input it posts the work to a thread pool like the following:

```
while (getline (file, input)){
        if(input =='a'){
            ioService_.post(boost::bind(&myClass::myFunction, this, input, counter));  
        } //end if

       else if(input=='b'){
            ioService_.post(boost::bind(importedFunction, input));
        }

       else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while

    threadpool.join_all();

}
```

The function importedFunction is imported from another class and the code works correctly with it but for the myFunction function it does not post work.

I was originally binding the function as this:

```
ioService_.post(boost::bind(myClass::myFunction, input, counter));
```

and it was giving me an error which is:

> /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:75:22: Type 'void
>   (multithreading::*)(std::__1::basic_string, int)' cannot be used
>   prior to '::' because it has no members

and then I changed into this and solved the error:

```
ioService_.post(boost::bind(&myClass::myFunction, this, input, counter));
```

but now the work is not submitted and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may have forgotten to `run()` the `io_service`.

If so, add

```
ioService_.run();
```

somehwere.

And perhaps read up about `io_service::work` to keep the service alive between tasks. It is possible that service threads completed the `run()` before you posted the work.

Comment: I did that, I have a routine where I initialize the pool i.e. creating the threads and create the work. If I only use the imported function it works whenever I use the function I created in my class it does not.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean with "imported function" and "myfunction" since we can't see anything of that. Please share a SSCCE that shows the problem.

Comment: for the imported function it is defined in another header #include class2 and I included he class in my file then I use it. My function is a function that I defined in the class that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. It is because of the `io_service::work`. The task this **Copy constructor notifies the io_service that work is starting**.

Here is a working example, if someone else needs it.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
    #include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

    #include <boost/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <boost/move/move.hpp>
    #include <boost/make_unique.hpp>

    namespace asio = boost::asio; 

    typedef boost::packaged_task<int> task_t;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<task_t> ptask_t;

    class Task
    {
      public:
        int execute(std::string command)
        {
          //TODO actual logic
          std::cout<< "\nThread:" << command << std::endl;
          int sum = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          {
            sum+=i;
          }
          return sum;
        }
    };


    void push_job(Task* worker, std::string seconds, boost::asio::io_service& io_service
                , std::vector<boost::shared_future<int> >& pending_data) {
      ptask_t task = boost::make_shared<task_t>(boost::bind(&Task::execute, worker, seconds));
      boost::shared_future<int> fut(task->get_future());
      pending_data.push_back(fut);
      io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), task));
    }

    int main()
    {
        Task* taskPtr = new Task();

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::thread_group threads;
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> service_work;
        service_work = boost::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);
        for (int i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() ; ++i)
        {
          threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
            &io_service));
        }
        std::vector<boost::shared_future<int> > pending_data; // vector of futures

        push_job(taskPtr, "4", io_service, pending_data);
        push_job(taskPtr, "5", io_service, pending_data);
        push_job(taskPtr, "6", io_service, pending_data);
        push_job(taskPtr, "7", io_service, pending_data);

        boost::wait_for_all(pending_data.begin(), pending_data.end());
        int total_sum = 0;
        for(auto result : pending_data){
           total_sum += result.get();
        }
        std::cout<< "Total sum: "<< total_sum << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```